# Php syntax error while trying to delete all rows or one row with same codes

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm writing a delete function in codeigniter. Users have two selection. Delete all or delete one row. I don't want to repeat same codes and I use a function like that. But there is an error ' Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE'. How can I solve that problem? Only way to repeat codes?

```
public function _delete_port()
{
    if ($_GET['delete_all']): 
        foreach ($_GET['delete_id'] as $delete_id):         
    else:
        $delete_id = $_GET['delete_id'];
    endif;
        // Some controls
        // ...

        $this->db->delete('ma_port', array('id' => $delete_id));

    if ($_GET['delete_all']) :
        endforeach;
    endif;

    redirect($url);
}
```

Comment: You have no body following the `foreach():`.  The alternate flow control syntax (using the `if/endif foreach/endforeach` is not recommended outside of HTML templating.  Use proper bracketed control structures and this stuff becomes easy to spot. `if () {...} else {...}` and `foreach() {... }`

Comment: Oh wait a minute, what are you trying to do here? It almost looks like you are attempting to procedurally construct the PHP code by conditionally starting and ending loops.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I must repeat the codes? Is it only solution?

Comment: *nested and dirty... So CHEARS*

Comment: @revo I must repeat the codes? Is it only solution?

Comment: @curiosity4834 I think I understand what your code is trying to do and I'll translate it into a working answer to explain what went wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue facing your code seems to be a misunderstanding of how flow control works. The approach you have taken is to attempt to use the `if / else / endif` to construct how you want *your code to look* instead of what *you want your code to do*.

Your procedure is to use a loop if `$_GET['delete_all']` is present as an array, and to otherwise use `$_GET['delete_id']`.  So first check the contents of the variables and then take the appropriate action.  The whole thing can be simplified by placing `$_GET['delete_id']` into an array if `$_GET['delete_all']` isn't there.

```
// Empty array we'll fill later
$delete_ids = array();

// If the delete_all array is available, use it as the array to delete from
if (isset($_GET['delete_all']) && is_array($_GET['delete_all'])) {
  $delete_ids = $_GET['delete_all'];
}
// Next if delete_id is present
else if (isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
  // Place it into the array to use later
  $delete_ids[] = $_GET['delete_id'];
}
else {
  // Neither was set, you have an error state, so handle it however you need to
  // Redirect, display an error, whatever.
}

// Now loop over your array and perform the action.
// The array either contains the original array from $_GET['delete_all'] or the single element $_GET['delete_id']
// Or it may be empty entirely, and therefore won't do anything
foreach ($delete_ids as $delete_id) {
  $this->db_delete('ma_port', array('id' => $delete_id));
}

// And finish with your redirect
redirect($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

That was so dirty, I should be a better translator thoguh:

```
public function _delete_port()
{
    if ($_GET['delete_all']): 
        foreach ($_GET['delete_id'] as $delete_id):         
            // Some controls
            // ...
            $this->db->delete('ma_port', array('id' => $delete_id));
        endforeach;
    else:
        $delete_id = $_GET['delete_id'];
        $this->db->delete('ma_port', array('id' => $delete_id));
    endif;
    redirect($url);
}
```